# Is there any way to make a First Person Shooter input in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, mouse, windows-8.1

I am working on a Windows 8.1 store game.
There is no specific need for the game to be a windows store app but I use it for development since I already had code for windows store and didn't bother to migrate the input and game loop code to a traditional desktop app.

The issue I am having now is that the Pointer(which can be a mouse/touch/pen) is bound to the screen's resolution.
I didn't find any way to work around it or to set the mouse cursor so I can't create a first person shooter like aimer or pointer.

I know it is possible to do so in a traditional win32 desktop app but I wonder if this limitation is only for Windows Store apps or will I encounter the same limitation in a traditional desktop app that runs on Windows 8.1?
In other words is this limitation a Windows 8.1 thing? Or a Windows store app thing?
Is there a way to create a FPS like mouse/aimer in a windows 8.1 store app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the app window bounds limitations and it is possibly even easier than in a Win32 app. The only thing you need to do is this:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null;
```

From now on handle this event to get the delta values when the mouse moves:

```
MouseDevice.GetForCurrentView().MouseMoved
```

I use it [here](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.cs).

Comment: Awesome, thanks it works. I saw this handler in the past but didn't use it because the MSDN documents said MouseDevice is an internal object that shouldn't be accessed.

Comment: "The MouseDevice supports the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
For mouse related input, use the Mouse class. The Mouse class represents the mouse to an application and provides methods, properties, and events that reflect the state of the mouse."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousedevice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That's WPF documentation, not WinRT documentation ;-)